# What does `:vo` means in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

likely a very simple SQL (oracle) question for you. See here a simplified example of my problem:

```
DELETE FROM schema.tablename
WHERE
    col1 = :v0
    AND col2 = :v1
    AND col3 = :v2
    ;
```

I don't know what :vo...:vo3 means and I have no idea what to google. Can you either explain it or give me some good literature on that ?

Comment: Here is a great literature to start learning [Oracle SQL](http://cfs6.tistory.com/upload_control/download.blog?fhandle=YmxvZzEwNjY3NUBmczYudGlzdG9yeS5jb206L2F0dGFjaC8wLzA3MDAwMDAwMDAwMC5wZGY%3D)

Answer (score 1):

it's called bind-variable , just think that those start with colon(:) is different  variable for binding value used in sql command.

Try imagine the use case of it.
"I want to delete records from table **schema.tablename**  by using where clause so I will remove those record that have col1 = **value1**  and col2 = **value2** and  col3 = **value3** "

Well ok then,how I write those above sql statement by not fixing the value of **value1,value2,value3** ?

the answer is using variable for binding the value!

:v0  - the variable that has name v0

:v1  - the variable that has name v1

:v2  - the variable that has name v2

ref.
https://www.oracletutorial.com/python-oracle/bind-variables/